# Подбор цвета в html

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться с цветами в HTML.

Задача простая, нужно  подобрать два цвета так, что бы они не отличались.

Я вставляю картинку в HTML у нее синий фон. С экрана с этой картинки со странички беру пипеткой цвет фона, получаю цвет `#2638AB`. Это цвет присваиваю в background-color дивке и перегружаю страницу. Цвет отличается от того, что на картинке. Беру пипеткой цвет с этого участка - `#1D239B`.

В чем проблема? Почему не совпадают цвета?

Comment: может быть проблема в пипетке?

Comment: а что, такое бывает? типа, пипетка проблемная?

Comment: Вероятно "цвет" фона - это не один цвет, фон состоит из многих цветов.

Comment: А пипетка то где? Да же если брать пипетки из разных редакторов, то цвета будут отличаться.

Comment: Уточняю пипетка - та что в маке стандартно поставляется.

Comment: Треш какой-то, поставил другую пипетку она другие цифры на этом же цветах дает. А как тогда точно отбирать цвета? Почему отличаются замеры?

Comment: @StepanKurakin  а что за пипетка ? с браузера ?

Comment: Автор, где используете пипетку? Если в Фотошопе, то у Вас проблема в несоответствии цветовых профилей. Уточните название приложения с пипеткой для более точного ответа.

Comment: Пипетка: "Цифровой колориметер" из стандартного набора программ mac os.